# Datagridview is all black on form load

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am using VB.Net is Visual Studio v16.6.3

I started getting this problem a few days ago on an application I developed two years ago and have been improving on and off. This error appeared out of now where. My DataGridView is OK at design time. when I launch the application, all forms that contain a DataGridView, it will appear all blacked out - as per image below.
[image: Image with blacked-out datagridview]

If I minimize the form and return to it, the datagridview is fine, as per image below:
[image: Image with refreshed datagridview]

I get the same problem, in design mode or on a compiled executable. I have not tried this on some elses computer yet to see if it is graphics-card related or application related. Anyone has any idea how to resolve it? I did notice that if I move the datagrid binding and display from the "new" contructor to the "shown" event, it sometimes fixes the problem - but not always. Very weird and random.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the DataGridView - has it been customised in any way?

Comment: My datagridview is not customized other than changing its properties - nothing fancy. But it does the same problem with all my datagridviews on all my forms. I deleted a datagridview and replaced it with a new one with all the defaults properties and it does the same thing.

Comment: Is the form and DataGridView DoubleBuffered?

Comment: Do you handle any of the DataGridViews events such as `CellFormatting` ?

Comment: To answer dbasnett, removing the doublebuffered only replaces the 'black' background by a datagridview that does not get refreshed.

Comment: To answer JayV, there is not cellformatting event on the ones that are having these problems.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found it. I have to call the Refresh for my datagridview... I don't know why. Did not have to do that before but it works.

If someone can explain the reason behind this behavior, please tell me.